# Printer driver cant install: /usr/bin/lpq: Error - unknown destination "/tmp"

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, 32-bit

I am trying to setup Xerox 7120 office printer on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit machine but am unable to install drivers.

After downloading linux drivers, extracting and executing (sudo ./setup) I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/lpq: Error - unknown destination "/tmp".
```

/tmp exists so I am not sure what the issue is exactly.

I also tried setting the rpinter up with PPD but it only print 3 lines of test type text and then continues printing blank pages until stopped.

Anyone have anything I can try to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar thread, where it's stated that the installer is searching in `/usr/bin` for both gzip and uncompress, but they reside in `/bin`, so a link has to be created:

```
ln -s /bin/gzip /usr/bin/gzip
ln -s /bin/uncompress /usr/bin/uncompress
```

That should fix the issue.

Comment: Seems too easy to be true, but will give it a try later this week :)

Comment: It should work. If it does not, please provide a link to the setup file (pastebin).